# Can I use Zookeeper to run my application?

Tags: apache-zookeeper

We have a bunch of servers. Each month we sort and merge data. We have processes created to run this, but currently they are run manually by our staff.

I want to automate this. I was thinking to use ZooKeeper.

So, these processes run on local machines, access data from a central data server, and write to local disk. Is this the kind of process ZooKeeper can monitor/execute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zookeeper is a wrong tool for the job. It is used for distributed process coordination via API. It can't start processes or monitor them.

It looks like you need something like [Rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) for job scheduling and management.